# svg.js - How to get X position from SVG text element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg.js

I want to get the position from a text element inside a SVG using svg.js but I always get 0. The position should be relative to the svg element, after that I would place anothe element over that text.

```js
window.onload=function(){
    let mapa = SVG('#map').size('100%', '100%');

    let txtText = SVG("#elements text").text();
    let posX = SVG("#elements text").x();
    let posVal = SVG("#elements text").has($(this).text() == "Messi");

    $(".results").html("Text " + txtText + " position X is: " + posX);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Calibri";
}
.results {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 5vh 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.12/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="results">asd</div>
<svg version="1.1" id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 553 492" enable-background="new 0 0 553 492" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="elements">
    <rect x="12" y="17" fill="#006633" width="525" height="462"/>
    <path fill="#339933" d="M495,130c-2,68.4,26,142-51,211s-116,131-244,63S-39,373,77,237S140,96,252,69s173-53,220-22S497,63,495,130
      z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 210.7305 325.9219)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-size="80px">Messi</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `text.rbox(svg)` to get a bounding box around the visual representation of your text relative to `svg`. With `box.x` you get the value you need

Comment: This option is working more precisely for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since the position is set by a transformation, you have to get it from the transformation info, like so:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    let mapa = SVG('#map').size('100%', '100%');

    let txtText = SVG("#elements text").text();
    let posVal = SVG("#elements text").has($(this).text() == "Messi");
    let posX = SVG("#elements text").transform().translateX*SVG("#elements text").transform().scaleX;

    $(".results").html("Text " + txtText + " position X is: " + posX);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Calibri";
}
.results {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 5vh 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.0.12/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="results">asd</div>
<svg version="1.1" id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 553 492" enable-background="new 0 0 553 492" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="elements">
    <rect x="12" y="17" fill="#006633" width="525" height="462"/>
    <path fill="#339933" d="M495,130c-2,68.4,26,142-51,211s-116,131-244,63S-39,373,77,237S140,96,252,69s173-53,220-22S497,63,495,130
      z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 210.7305 325.9219)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-size="80px">Messi</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```